# Hadoop input.FileSplit cannot be case to mapred.FileSplit

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to get the file name in a Hadoop Mapper, using the following code:

```
FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit) context.getInputSplit();
String filename = fileSplit.getPath().getName();
```

The library I have imported is:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit;
```

I get the exception:

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileSplit
```

Could someone please help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's right there - Your import line is wrong because return InputSplit implementation using `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit`

Why aren't you importing `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit`? both implementations fulfill the contract of `InputSplit` so it should be seamless, unless some other methods class explicitly requires a specific `FileSplit` implementation.